# How to know the height the space left on a browser by the menus, bookmarks and tabs?

Tags: html, layout, css

I want make a page (HTML + CSS) that fits all the space left on the browser without horizontal and vertical scrollbars.

Now you are readind this question on a web browser and, probably, you can see horizontal scrollbar. I want to use this space without using horizontal and vertical scrollbars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` and its friends.

Check out [this great table](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html) on quirksmode.org for an overview on which variables are supported by which browser.

**Edit: Pure CSS**

In CSS you have `width: 100%` and `height: 100%`. If those work for your scenario, use them. To avoid scroll bars, you can use `overflow: hidden` on the body, but be very careful because this prevents scrolling completely. It depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Is this javascript? Is there another css equivalence?